# Convert Mongodb Aggregation Pipeline to C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation

Perhaps someone can help me out with a problem to convert a mongodb aggregation query to C# using the mongodb .Net driver.

According to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331385/mongodb-except-equivalent) I tried to convert the following to C#

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    { "$facet": {
        "allInRoot1": [{
            "$match": { "rootReferenceId": LUUID("9f3a73df-bca7-48b7-b111-285359e50a02") }
        }],
        "allInRoot2": [{
            "$match": { "rootReferenceId": LUUID("27f2b4a6-5471-406a-a39b-1e0b0f8c4eb9") }
        }]
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "difference": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$allInRoot1",
                "as": "this",
                "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this.reference.id", { "$setDifference": [ "$allInRoot1.reference.id", "$allInRoot2.reference.id" ] } ] }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

So far I have this

```cs
        var matchFilterOne = new ExpressionFilterDefinition<NodeModel>(node => node.RootReferenceId == baseId);
        var matchStageOne  = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(matchFilterOne);
        var pipelineOne = PipelineDefinition<NodeModel, NodeModel>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] { matchStageOne });

        var matchFilterTwo = new ExpressionFilterDefinition<NodeModel>(node => node.RootReferenceId == idToExclude);
        var matchStageTwo = PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(matchFilterTwo);
        var pipelineTwo = PipelineDefinition<NodeModel, NodeModel>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] { matchStageTwo });

        var facetPipelineOne = AggregateFacet.Create("allInRoot1", pipelineOne);
        var facetPipelineTwo = AggregateFacet.Create("allInRoot2", pipelineTwo);
        var test = testCollection.Aggregate()
            .Facet(facetPipelineOne, facetPipelineTwo)
            /* This seems to fail because the facet structure is wrong and it can't access the $allInRoot1 field ...

            .Project(@"{
                'difference': {
                    '$filter': {
                        'input': '$allInRoot1',
                        'as': 'this',
                        'cond': {
                            '$in': [ '$$this.reference.id', { '$setDifference': [ '$allInRoot1.reference.id', '$allInRoot2.reference.id' ] }]
                        }
                 }}}")
            */
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Perhaps someone has a clue pointing me in the right direction? Is it also possible to use the projection with types?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Create a mongo collection Using c# then you may use Linq or Lambda expressions to querying

Comment: Oh, I already have a mongo collection and I am working with it. In the code it is testCollection.

Comment: You seems to be good in mongo querying,in this case it's nothing to you to convert  your queries into Linq or lambda expressions.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Perhaps I should just use the query as it is. Most of  the types does not work well anyway. E.g. AggregatedFacetResults inside the projection stage. I am not sure if it is compatible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution so far that i've seen is copying the whole aggregation array into **MongoDbCompass's** Aggregations tab and then export it in C#.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the original question. I suggest reading the Stack Overflow answer guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . For this specific question if it's not possible your answer should explain that and explain the work around.